# jQuery - remove li from array with delete image

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cookies

I'm attempting to make a menu bar that can have `<li>` elements added and removed. So far so good, but when I try and remove them I'm running into issues. I've toyed with this for a couple hours and now I'm wondering if this whole process could just be made easier (maybe an object?).

Anyways, here's the full code (80 lines), with comments to follow along.

```
var tabs = $('.accountSelectNav');
var titles = [];
var listItems = [];
// when the page loads check if tabs need to be added to the ul (menu bar)
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if ($.cookie('listItems') != null) {
        console.log('not null');
            //return "listItems" to it's array form.
        listItems = JSON.parse($.cookie('listItems'));
        $('.accountSelectNav').append(listItems);
    }
});

$('.selectTable td:first-child').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#home_select').removeClass('navHighlight');
    //grab the text value of this cell
    title = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        url:'core/functions/getAccountId.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'title' : title}
    }).fail (function() {
        alert('error');
    }).done(function(data) {
        accountId = $.trim(data);
        // store values in the cookie
        $.cookie('account_id', accountId, {expires : 7});
        $.cookie('title', title, {expires : 7});
        window.location = ('home_table.php');
    });

    // make sure the value is NOT currently in the array. Then add it 
    var found = jQuery.inArray(title, titles);
    if (found == -1) {
        titles.push(title);
        addTab();
    }

    // make sure the value is NOT currently in the array. Then add it
    found = jQuery.inArray(title, listItems);
    if (found == -1) {
        addListItem();
        //place <li>'s in cookie so they may be used on multiple pages
        $.cookie('listItems', JSON.stringify(listItems));
    };
});

$("body").on("click", ".deleteImage", function (e) {
    var removeTitle = $(this).closest('li').find('a').text();
    var removeItem = $(this).closest('li')[0].outerHTML;

    //remove title from "titles" array
    titles = jQuery.grep(titles, function (value) {
        return value != removeTitle;
    });
    //remove <li> from "listItems" array
    listItems = jQuery.grep(listItems, function (value) {
        return value != removeItem;
    });
    // this shows the <li> is still in the listItemsarray
    console.log(listItems); 
    // put the array back in the cookie
    $.cookie('listItems', JSON.stringify(listItems));
    removeTab(this);
});

$("body").on("mouseover", ".accountSelectNav li", function(e) {
    $(this).find('.deleteImage').show();
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", ".accountSelectNav li", function(e) {
    $(this).find('.deleteImage').hide();
});

function addTab() {
    tabs.append('<li class="navHighlight">' + '<a href="#">' + title + '</a>' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage"/>' + '</a>' + '</li>');
};

function removeTab(del) {
    $(del).closest('li').remove();
}

function addListItem() {
    var s = ('<li class="navHighlight">' + '<a href="#">' + title + '</a>' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage"/>' + '</a>' + '</li>');
    listItems.push(s);
}
```

So you see I have two arrays of equal length that should always be the same length. One stores the title to be displayed in the tab, the other holds the html for the `<li>` which will be appended to the `<ul>`. I have no problem removing the title from its array. However removing the `<li>` from it's array is becoming a rather big hassle. You see when I get the `<li>` element after its been inflated the html inside does not ***exactly*** match what was put in, the browser adds style elements.

Example, the variable "removeItem" represents the html value of the selected `<li>` I wish to remove. It looks like this:

```
<li class="navHighlight"><a href="#">Test1</a><a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage" style="display: inline;"></a></li>
```

yet the value in my array "listItems" looks like this:

```
<li class="navHighlight"><a href="#">Test1</a><a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage"/></a></li>
```

So my attempt at removing it from my array always fails because they aren't a perfect match.

Now my question is how do I remove this `<li>` item? Also is there an easier way to do this whole process and I'm just not seeing it?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Fiddle by request [here](http://jsfiddle.net/62KXs/1/)

Easiest way I can explain it.

Click the link to the fiddle. 
Click any cell in the "App Name" column 
This will add a `<li>` to the `<ul>` (menu) above of the table 
When you hover over the `<li>` a picture appears 
Click the picture 
This *should* remove the `<li>`, both from the `<ul>` and from the array listItems 

right now it does not

Comment: There's a lot to process here. Can you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and post it to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: ya, sorry. I try to avoid lengthy posts, but I figured if I didn't include all the details I would just end up adding and editing to this post 100 times.

Comment: Comprehension is not my finest quality... thats a lot of lines

Comment: Yeah, make a jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net so we can see the problem easily.

Comment: @JamesG. fiddle ready

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist fiddle ready

Comment: @i_me_mine Sorry, I'm still very lost.

Comment: I'm still having a _lot_ of trouble understanding your code and what you're trying to do. One thing it looks like you're overcomplicating is storing the entire HTML in the cookie. If it's the same for every element, consider just storing the value (like "Test1") then defining a function to wrap it in the template of HTML you are using. That would completely sidestep your problem, and there are likely other simplifications you could make that would make life easier, given how hard your code is to follow.

Comment: Matching against the full HTML of each <li> is going to be pretty fragile.  You might consider adding an identifying classname to each one, to make it easier to match against.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yea, that's the real problem, it's super fragile, and not at all accurate

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I posted my solution, it was directly due to your help. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the process of making this easier to check, I've taken your JSFiddle and did the following:

- removed extra console.log and comments
- removed interaction with cookies (since I did not have them in the first place, I figured they wouldn't just the first scenario)

After doing so I reached a point (you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/62KXs/6/)) where the desired functionality just works.

I even went ahead and removed the ajax stuff because that alert was driving me crazy. ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/62KXs/7/))

Since this works fine, my guess is that your issue lies between the lines that I removed.

Your usage of cookies is as follows:

1. To load existing tabs and add them back again
2. To save `account_id` and `title`, which is not used back again
3. To persist the `listItems` after a new item has been added

I then opened up the console with your version of the fiddle and the execution of javascript stops at `$.cookie()` with the error `undefined is not a function`.

This clearly indicates that the issue present in the Fiddle is that jQuery.cookie is not present and so those calls are halting the execution of the rest of your script. This also explains why it just started working when I took them out.

I posted the whole process of how I got there to indicate how I trimmed down the problem to specific parts, which is useful to reduce the problem space. When you're out of options and reach a place when you're lost, it's easier to post a question with less code and the specific part of the problem that you've identified. This will help you in finding the issues that you're facing and StackOverflow to provide proper answers to your questions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're 100% correct. The cookie and AJAX make everything seem much more complicated than it actually is. I am working on a solution with my code (trimmed) I'll post it when I'm done. As for now, answer accepted. Thanks for the help and the advice!

Comment: I added my solution with a rather lengthy explanation. Should be an easy although somewhat long read.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with. It should be much easier for people to understand than my original post. Although it's a long read it may be worth it, especially for new developers.

The point of this code is to make a menu bar out of an un-ordered list or `<ul>`. The menu bar needs to be used on multiple pages. So I'll be using cookies.

I start with this code to get a text value from my table.:

```
$('.selectTable td:first-child').on('click', function(e) {
    // This value will be used later for the name of the tab or `<li>` inside our menu bar or `<ul>`
    title = $(this).text();
});
```

Then I place the value in an array. I do this ***only*** if the array does not already have this string inside it. I do not want duplicates:

```
var found = jQuery.inArray(title, titles);
var titles = [];
if (found == -1) {
    titles.push(title);
}
```

Then I store the array into a cookie, using a [library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) like this:

```
$.cookie('titles', JSON.stringify(titles));
```

Now when any page loads that needs this menu bar I run this code to check if there are any values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('titles') != null) {
        titles = JSON.parse($.cookie('titles'));
    }
});
```

Now I need to loop through the array. When I loop through the array I have to do 3 things:

1) Grab the string value. 
2) Add the `html` to my new string so it becomes a list item or `<li>`.
3) Append the newly created `<li>` to our `<ul>`.

Like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    var str = titles[i];
    var listItem = '<li class="navHighlight">' 
                    + '<a href="#">' 
                    + str 
                    + '</a>' 
                    + '<a href="#">' 
                    + '<img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage"/>' 
                    + '</a>' 
                    + '</li>';
    $('.accountSelectNav').append(listItem);
}
```

Now, if I want to remove this `<li>` I click the delete image found inside our `<li>`. What delete image you say? Look at the `html` I added again. You will see I add an `<img>` tag in there.

Now delete like so:

```
$("body").on("click", ".deleteImage", function (e) {
    // grabs the text value of my li, which I want to remove
    var removeTitle = $(this).closest('li').find('a').text();
    // runs through my titles array and returns an array without the value above
    titles = jQuery.grep(titles, function (value) {
        return value != removeTitle;
    });
});
```

Then I simply place the new array inside my cookie once again. Like this:

```
$.cookie('titles', JSON.stringify(titles));
```

And finally I remove the tab like this:

```
removeTab(this);

function removeTab(del) {
    $(del).closest('li').remove();
}
```

Yay, I'm done. So now, if anyone has a more elegant way of accomplishing this I'm listening. I have no doubt there's a better way, javascript/jQuery isn't even close to my strong point.

The full code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/v65XHfrR).

Comment: Certainly looks like you've simplified things, which is good. Maybe think about whether you're certain you want to rely on a cookie (which can be turned off) and if so, what you want to use as a fallback (in case they ARE off).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I don't like the idea of a cookie. To be honest though I don't know any other way to store these with jQuery. I mean I think a database table for this is a little overkill. Don't you?